# Use yeomen generator branch locally

Tags: git, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm using https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack locally, but I would like the generator to use a branch of that project.

So I have installed it using

```
npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack
```

1) What would be the next steps if I would like to use the `canary` branch of that project and continue to use it as if I was using the master branch?

2) If the branch gets merged into the master branch, what would I need to do then?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you wish to use canary branch you need to checkout this branch.

**`git checkout -b canary`**

2. Once you merge it you can delete it or continue to work on it and merge it again several times as your on going work.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use the `canary` verison of the generator, you can use `npm` to install the branch directly, then simply use it like a regular generator:

```
npm uninstall -g generator-angular-fullstack
npm install -g https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack.git#canary
yo generator-angular-fullstack
```